# Safari 11 - Autoplay Youtube Issue

Tags: javascript, youtube, safari

The following works on all modern desktop browsers apart from Safari 11 where 'onStateChange' seems to fire constantly which I believe is what causes the following error:

'Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 413 (HTTP/2.0 413)'

Stranger still. The video will actually start playing if I click anywhere on the page.

edit:
FYI I have tried autoplay=1 within the api AND by adding the &autoplay=1 to the src of the iframe after the fact.

```
var tag = document.createElement('script');

  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
  //    after the API code downloads.
  var player;
  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    var player;
          player = new YT.Player('player', {
            videoId: 'ID-HERE',
            playerVars: { 'autoplay': 0, 'controls': 0 },
            events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
        }
      });
  }



  // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
  function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.playVideo();
      $('#player').delay(1200).fadeIn()
   }

  // 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
  //    The function indicates that when playing a video (state=1),
  //    the player should play for six seconds and then stop.

  function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    // if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {


      console.log('state change, play');
      event.target.playVideo();

  }

  function stopVideo() {
    console.log('video stop');
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change:

event.target.playVideo();
to
player.playVideo();

Here it's works fine. I had the same issue here with this version of Safari.
When I changed this way, it worked fine with every others browsers.

Comment: I'll try this fix when I get time. I ended up switching to Vimeo embed. Just had to fudge hiding the controls. Currently testing Vimeo internally to see if it fixes the problem.